# get taxonomy thumbnail and use it as a variable in code

Tags: php, categories, woocommerce-offtopic, javascript, thumbnails

Im having trouble trying to retrieve category thumbnails and use as a variable in some code i got from a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z82yu9j1/). It puts a placeholder image as default and displays a category image on hover of category list.

I havent been able to get the placeholder or category image to show.

I have tried wp_get_attachment_url, get_term_thumbnail and get_term_meta to try and retrieve the thumbnail, however I am not even sure if these have or havent worked as I am not sure how to incorporate my resulting variable "$image" into the code.

```
    $args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
    'title_li'   => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'echo'       => 0,
    'show_count' => 0,
    'style'      => '',
    'parent'    => 0
    );

    $get_cats = get_terms( $args );

    foreach ( $get_cats as $cat ) {
       $image = get_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_bid', true );        
?>
        <div class="design">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul class="hoverimage">
                <?php
                echo '<ul class="menu-item" data-image="$image"><a href="' . get_term_link( $cat ) . '">' . $cat->name . '</a></ul>'; 
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="zoom-preview">
            <div class="img_container">
            </div>
        </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<?php
    }
?>



<script>

$(function(){
    var imageContainer = '.img_container',
        imageList      = '.hoverimage',
        maxWidth       = 'parent', // parent or specific css width/  
        defImage       = '/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Logo-02-02.jpg';
    var $imageContainer = $(imageContainer).eq(0);
    var $imageList      = $(imageList).eq(0);
    if (maxWidth === 'parent') { maxWidth = $imageContainer.width() + 'px'; }
    //Load images and set hover::
    $imageList.find('li').each(function(index){
        if (typeof $(this).data('image') === 'string') {
            $imageContainer.append(
                "<img id='imageToggle"+index+
                "' src='"+$(this).data('image')+
                "' style='max-width: "+maxWidth+"; display:none;' />"
            );
            $(this).data("image","imageToggle"+index);
            $(this).hover(
                function(){ loadImage($(this).data('image')); },
                function(){ loadImage('imageToggleDef'); }
            );  
        }
    });
    //Load default:
    $imageContainer.append(
                "<img id='imageToggleDef"+
                "' src='"+defImage+
                "' style='max-width: "+maxWidth+"' />"
    );
    //Toggle images:
    function loadImage(imageId) {
        $imageContainer.stop(true).fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $(this).find('img').hide();
            $(this).find('img#'+imageId).show();
            $(this).fadeIn('fast');
        });
    }

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat' in your code, so most likely you have Woocommerce, and we need to get a category picture from there.
Try this code

```
<?php           $args = array(
                'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
                'title_li'   => '',
                'hide_empty' => 0,
                'echo'       => 0,
                'show_count' => 0,
                'style'      => '',
                'parent'    => 0
                );

                $get_cats = get_terms( $args );
?>
<div class="design">
   <div class="menu">
    3 menu options will be in this div and when we hover at each link an image must appear to the right with fast zoom in effect like shooting.
       <ul class="hoverimage">
<?php

                foreach ( $get_cats as $cat ) {

                $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); 
                $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); 
    if($image == "") {
    $image = get_bloginfo('url') . '/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/Logo-02-02.jpg';
    }
            ?>

        <li class="menu-item" data-image="<?php echo $image; ?>"><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $cat ); ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>

            <?php
                }
            ?>
       </ul>
   </div>
    <div class="zoom-preview">
image will appear here when we hover at each link at the left. each link it's own image.
        Also there must be a default image here when we do not hover at any link at the left.
        <div class='img_conatainer'>
        </div>
    </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>         
            <script>


$(function(){
    var imageContainer = '.img_conatainer',
        imageList      = '.hoverimage',
        maxWidth       = 'parent', // parent or specific css width/  
        defImage       = 'http://cdn.instructables.com/FEB/Q2RO/H9G190RM/FEBQ2ROH9G190RM.LARGE.jpg';
    var $imageContainer = $(imageContainer).eq(0);
    var $imageList      = $(imageList).eq(0);
    if (maxWidth === 'parent') { maxWidth = $imageContainer.width() + 'px'; }
    //Load images and set hover::
    $imageList.find('li').each(function(index){
        if (typeof $(this).data('image') === 'string') {
            $imageContainer.append(
                "<img id='imageToggle"+index+
                "' src='"+$(this).data('image')+
                "' style='max-width: "+maxWidth+"; display:none;' />"
            );
            $(this).data("image","imageToggle"+index);
            $(this).hover(
                function(){ loadImage($(this).data('image')); },
                function(){ loadImage('imageToggleDef'); }
            );  
        }
    });
    //Load default:
    $imageContainer.append(
                "<img id='imageToggleDef"+
                "' src='"+defImage+
                "' style='max-width: "+maxWidth+"' />"
    );
    //Toggle images:
    function loadImage(imageId) {
        $imageContainer.stop(true).fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $(this).find('img').hide();
            $(this).find('img#'+imageId).show();
            $(this).fadeIn('fast');
        });
    }

});

            </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but still nothing showing up. Yes I have Woocommerce. Where would I put the $image variable in the second section of the code? I think this is what is missing in bringing the 2 separate sections of code together.

Comment: Ok, try edited code. We no need put image in second part. If dont work - open html  page source and try to find this output. Then copy it here.

Comment: This is the output for one of the product categories

<div class="design">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul class="hoverimage">
<li class="menu-item" data-image=""><a href="https://www.aaa.com/product-category/da-vinci/">Da Vinci</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="zoom-preview">
                <div class="img_container">
                </div>
            </div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

Comment: oh and the code didnt work, it just added bullet points to the list

Comment: Ok, try edited code. Its 100% that you have any images at categories ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. The previous page source output i pasted was of a category without thumbnail. Some do some dont. I have just checked again with 1 that does have an image and "data-image" shows the image url, however no image displays on the site.

Comment: Ok, try edited code

Comment: The results are completely random. The thumbnails are now showing anywhere from 1 in every 3 page refreshes up to 1 in every 20 and most often on the higher end. I cant see why this would work just sometimes. I also read that get_woocommerce_term_meta was deprecated so I tried get_term_meta, no difference.